# Brick Breaker - Adjust ball's collision angle without affecting speed

Tags: java, collision-detection, physics, swing

I'm working on a Java Brick Breaker game, and it's functional so far. However, I'm facing an issue with collisions. Currently, when the ball collides it simply reverses its direction.

I want to implement a feature where the ball's collision angle can change depending on where it hits the paddle, [similar to what's shown in this picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoO4t.png)

Currently, my Ball object only has x and y coordinates, and the ball's speed is constant for each frame (e.g. ±1x/±1y). However, my challenge is to modify the ball's direction without affecting its speed. In other words, if I try to make the ball move more horizontally than vertically (e.g., ±3x/±1y), it currently appears to move 3 times faster because it's covering more pixels in the horizontal direction per frame.

Here's the relevant code (I took snippets instead of a code dump):

```java
class Ball {

    // Global variables.
    public int x, y; // x, y coordinates of ball
    boolean move_up, move_left; // Direction of ball
    public Slider slider;
    public ArrayList<Brick> brickList;
    public Timer timer;
    private boolean gameOver;
    public final int ballDiameter = 20;
    public final int ballRadius = ballDiameter/2;

    public Ball(Slider s, ArrayList<Brick> b) {
        this.slider = s;
        this.brickList = b;
        this.x = 220;
        this.y = 480;
        this.move_up = true;
        this.move_left = true;
        this.gameOver = false;
    }

    public void paintBall(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2d.setColor(Color.red);
        g2d.fillOval(x, y, ballDiameter, ballDiameter);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
    }

    public Rectangle getBounds() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, ballDiameter, ballDiameter);
    }

    public boolean sliderCollision() {
        return slider.getBounds().intersects(getBounds());
    }

    public Brick brickCollision() {
        for (Brick brick : brickList) {
            if (brick.getBounds().intersects(getBounds())) {
                return brick;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isGameOver() {
        return this.gameOver;
    }

    public void setGameOver(boolean b) {this.gameOver = b;}
    public void disable() {}
}
...
...
...

class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    private BufferedImage background;

    Slider slider = new Slider(200, 500, 100, 30);
    ArrayList<Brick> brickList = new ArrayList<Brick>();
    Ball ball = new Ball(slider, brickList);

    Timer gameTimer;
    JLabel welcomeSign;
    JLabel scoreLabel;
    boolean isGameRunning = false;
    int score;

    public void startBall() {
        // The timer is used to repaint the component.
        ball.timer = new Timer(5, new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                // If ball hits the slider
                if (ball.sliderCollision()) {
                    increaseScore(10);
                    // Go Up
                    if (ball.x + ball.ballDiameter >= slider.getBounds().x &&
                            ball.x <= slider.getBounds().x + slider.getBounds().width &&
                            ball.y + ball.ballDiameter - 1 <= slider.getBounds().y) {
                        System.out.println("Move up!");
                        /* Here will be the calculation of the new angle */
                        ball.move_up = true;
                    } 
                    // Go Down
                    else if (ball.x + ball.ballDiameter >= slider.getBounds().x && //
                            ball.x <= slider.getBounds().x + slider.getBounds().width &&
                            ball.y >= slider.getBounds().y + slider.getBounds().height - 1) {
                        System.out.println("Move down!");
                        ball.move_up = false;
                    }
                    // Go Left
                    else if (ball.x <= slider.getBounds().x &&
                            ball.y > slider.getBounds().y - ball.ballDiameter &&
                            ball.y < slider.getBounds().y + slider.getBounds().height) {
                        System.out.println("Go Left");
                        ball.move_left = true;
                    } 
                    // Go Right
                    else if (ball.x >= slider.getBounds().x + slider.getBounds().width - 1 &&
                            ball.y > slider.getBounds().y - ball.ballDiameter &&
                            ball.y < slider.getBounds().y + slider.getBounds().height) {
                        System.out.println("Go Right");
                        ball.move_left = false;
                    }
                }

                // If the ball hits a brick
                Brick hitBrick = ball.brickCollision();
                if (hitBrick != null) {
                    increaseScore(100);
                    // Go Up
                    if (ball.x + ball.ballDiameter >= hitBrick.getBounds().x &&
                            ball.x <= hitBrick.getBounds().x + hitBrick.getBounds().width &&
                            ball.y + ball.ballDiameter - 1 <= hitBrick.getBounds().y) {
                        ball.move_up = true;
                        // Go Down
                    } else if (ball.x + ball.ballDiameter >= hitBrick.getBounds().x && //
                            ball.x <= hitBrick.getBounds().x + hitBrick.getBounds().width &&
                            ball.y >= hitBrick.getBounds().y + hitBrick.getBounds().height - 1) {
                        ball.move_up = false;
                        // Go Left
                    } else if (ball.x <= hitBrick.getBounds().x &&
                            ball.y > hitBrick.getBounds().y - ball.ballDiameter &&
                            ball.y < hitBrick.getBounds().y + hitBrick.getBounds().height) {
                        ball.move_left = true;
                        // Go Right
                    } else if (ball.x >= hitBrick.getBounds().x + hitBrick.getBounds().width - 1 &&
                            ball.y > hitBrick.getBounds().y - ball.ballDiameter &&
                            ball.y < hitBrick.getBounds().y + hitBrick.getBounds().height) {
                        ball.move_left = false;
                    }

                    // Reduce health of brick and remove from screen if no health
                    if (hitBrick.reduceHealth() < 1) {
                        brickList.remove(hitBrick);
                    }
                }

                // If ball hits bottom
                if (ball.y > getHeight() - ball.ballDiameter) {
                    ball.setGameOver(true);
                    return;
                }

                // If the ball hits ceiling
                if (ball.y < 0) {
                    ball.move_up = false;
                }

                if (ball.move_up) {
                    ball.y -= 1;  // Move ball up 1 pixel
                } else {
                    ball.y += 1;  // Move ball down 1 pixel
                }

                // If ball hits right wall
                if (ball.x > 500 - ball.ballDiameter) {
                    ball.move_left = true;
                }

                // If ball hits left wall
                if (ball.x < 0) {
                    ball.move_left = false;
                }

                if (ball.move_left) {
                    ball.x -= 1;  // Move ball left 1 pixel
                } else {
                    ball.x += 1;  // Move ball right 1 pixel
                }
                repaint();
            }
        });
        ball.timer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: You may be interested in past Q&A like [How can I make an entity move in a direction](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/36046/39518), [A more sophisticated ball-paddle collision algorithm for Breakout](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/20456/39518), [How to make sprite move in any direction](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/20456/39518), [Collisions reflecting ball velocities incorrectly](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/51232/39518), etc.

Comment: I found all these by [searching for posts tagged "Java" with keywords "angle" and "speed"](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?page=1&tab=Relevance&pagesize=15&q=angle%20speed%20%5bjava%5d&searchOn=3). Since you're far from the first developer to try to make a brick breaker game in Java in the more than a decade this site has been around, you can often find the info you need in existing posts, without needing to wait for new answers to be written.

Comment: At a glance, one thing that jumps out to me is that your representation for the ball essentially uses boolean for trajectory. That is going to *significantly* limit the number of angles the ball can have. You *could* kludge around that, but a more elegant solution would be to use an abstraction that allows for more options: i.e. tracking degrees for your trajectory heading or using a 2D heading vector.